# Angular misses sometimes to update bound values

Tags: angularjs

We detected a strange case where sometimes angularJS fails to update bound value. At the moment we know how to workaround but not why this malfunction happens.

Does anyone have a glue what is wrong with the defective version?

common:

```
app.factory("DATASOURCE", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
    return $resource(URL);
}]);

...
var self = this;  // effective $scope
self.service = DATASOURCE;
```

defective version

```
var self = this;
self.objectRequest = self.service.get();
self.objectRequest.$promise.then(function(pRes) {
    self.objectTree = pRes; // resolve or not 8-(
})
```

the first time this version works as expected. The following calls sometimes shows that strange behavior:

pRes has new values (checked with debugger), however,
bound values still show the previous state

```
 {{objectTree.head}}
```

The debugger does report neither failure nor exceptions

Later calls may update the bound values.

workaround:

```
var self = this;
self.objectRequest = self.service.get();
self.objectRequest.$promise.then(function(pRes) {
    self.objectTree.head = pRes.head; // resolve
    self.objectTree.table = pRes.table; // resolve
    self.objectTree.messages = pRes.messages; // resolve
})
```

We would like to understand what is going (wr)on(g).

Comment: please make a plunker reproducing the wrong behavior

Comment: A simple guess is that the update is done outside the angular lifecycle. It depends how you bind the objectTree to the $scope or controller. I think you just need to add a `$scope.$apply` or a `$scope.digest`.

Comment: Too less code is shown here to help you. Another guess is that the scope instance can change due to the use of ng-if, switch, controller, etc. You will have to provide more detail.

Comment: Not sure why you're overwriting `objectTree` with your callback result...? Would probably solve it by creating a new `self` variable to hold your view data; also, keep your promises/services out of the `$scope`, is a general rule I live by.

Comment: Possibly an issue because you're reusing the same $promise object? I thought a promise could only be resolved once.